# Security Html and PhP

Tags: php, html, security

can some one tell me what this following code does and what is the problem here in terms of security?

```
 < ?php require_once '../include/' . $_GET['file']?>
```

i think that this _Get['file'] gets an argument and includes into the library i guess? im not sure, and also not sure about the problem in this code.

Comment: you are taking the straight user input without validation.

Comment: and why is this bad for the security of the webserver? Ty for the answer

Comment: It lets them execute any file that is in the `../include/` directory. Never ever trust data provided by a user.

Comment: what if they pass in some private file name or path?

Comment: Ty very much. I understand.

Answer (score 0):

This allows the client to make the webserver execute almost any PHP script on the server. They can even execute files outside the `../include` directory by including their own `../` sequences in the parameter, e.g.

```
yourscript.php?file=../../../somescript.php
```

This will then execute

```
require_once("../include/../../../somescript.php");
```

which is equivalent to

```
require_once("../../somescript.php");
```